# AWS ec2 instance not running updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been having problems with my ec2 instance, I tried running a "sudo yum update" today, it froze for a while on Cleanup of the last file.  I had to C^ escape out of it, now when I log into ec2 in terminal it says the updates are still needed, but when I try and run it again it says "No packages marked for update"

Any advice?

Comment: Spin up an new EC2 with a newer AMI.

Comment: Whatever is happening, it would be related to the Operating System and whatever you have installed/configured on the instance. It isn't related to Amazon EC2 itself. Is there anything important installed on the instance? Can you move it off to a new instance as @JeremyThompson suggested?